# C# chart, how to get the maximum x-axis value?

Tags: c#

I know this might be a silly question, but can someone please tell me: given a point collection, how to find the maximum x-axis value?  Ii.e: the x value of the right most point?

I see one function like this:

```
chart1.Series["XXX"].Points.FindMaxByValue()
```

but seems like it only finds the maximum Y-axis value.

Comment: Not sure but could it be like  this:- chart1.Series["XXX"].AxisX.Maximum.ToString()??

Comment: @RahulTripathi That's the correct answer if you remove the ".ToString()"

Comment: @MatthewWatson:- Added that as an answer !!!

Answer (score 0):

Just got the confirmation from [@Matthew Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106159/matthew-watson) that it is the correct answer what I have put in comments:-

So you can try with:-

```
chart1.Series["XXX"].AxisX.Maximum
```